# GLSL uniform mat4 is always 0

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glsl

I am trying to load a orthographic projection matrix into a shader, but when I go to run the code and I click around in the window I end up with all the points going to (0,0,0) which I'm guessing is being caused by the uniform matrix never being setup and as a result everything is being multiplied by 0. I am using Qt, OpenGL and GLM for this. Any ideas why this would be happening?

I have been debugging it a little and it seems to be having issues at the point where I'm loading the matrix into the shader in resizeGL and initializeGL, not sure of the cause though.

Thanks in advance!

My Class handling all of the OpenGL Stuff:

```
GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) : QOpenGLWidget(parent), outline(false), drawMode(0) {
    num_pts = 0;
    drawMode = GL_POINTS;
    next = 1;

    ortho = glm::ortho(0.0f, 640.0f, 480.0f, 0.0f);

}

GLWidget::~GLWidget() {
}

void GLWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) {
    switch (event->key()) {
    case Qt::Key_C:
        cout << "Cleared all the points." << endl;
        num_pts = 0;

        pts.clear();

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
        break;
    case Qt::Key_W:
        outline = !outline;
        if (outline) {
            cout << "Displaying outlines." << endl;
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
        }
        else {
            cout << "Displaying filled polygons." << endl;
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
        }
        break;
    case Qt::Key_Space:
        switch (next) {
        case(0):
            drawMode = GL_POINTS;

            cout << "drawMode is GL_POINTS" << endl;

            next = 1;
            break;
        case(1):
            drawMode = GL_LINES;

            cout << "drawMode is GL_LINES" << endl;

            next = 2;
            break;
        case(2):
            drawMode = GL_LINE_STRIP;

            cout << "drawMode is GL_LINE_STRIP" << endl;

            next = 3;
            break;
        case(3):
            drawMode = GL_LINE_LOOP;

            cout << "drawMode is GL_LINE_LOOP" << endl;

            next = 4;
            break;
        case(4):
            drawMode = GL_TRIANGLES;

            cout << "drawMode is GL_TRIANGLES" << endl;

            next = 5;
            break;
        case(5):
            drawMode = GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP;

            cout << "drawMode is GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP" << endl;

            next = 6;
            break;
        case(6):
            drawMode = GL_TRIANGLE_FAN;

            cout << "drawMode is GL_TRIANGLE_FAN" << endl;

            next = 0;
            break;
        }
        break;
    case Qt::Key_P:

        cout << "Projection Location: " << projectionMatrixLoc << endl << endl;

        cout << "Projection Matrix:" << endl << endl;
        cout << "------------" << endl;
        cout << ortho[0][0] << " ";
        cout << ortho[1][0] << " ";
        cout << ortho[2][0] << " ";
        cout << ortho[3][0] << endl;
        cout << "------------" << endl;
        cout << ortho[0][1] << " ";
        cout << ortho[1][1] << " ";
        cout << ortho[2][1] << " ";
        cout << ortho[3][1] << endl;
        cout << "------------" << endl;
        cout << ortho[0][2] << " ";
        cout << ortho[1][2] << " ";
        cout << ortho[2][2] << " ";
        cout << ortho[3][2] << endl;
        cout << "------------" << endl;
        cout << ortho[0][3] << " ";
        cout << ortho[1][3] << " ";
        cout << ortho[2][3] << " ";
        cout << ortho[3][3] << endl;
        cout << "------------" << endl << endl << endl;

        break;
    }
    update();
}

void GLWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {

    glm::vec2 temp = glm::vec2(0.0);
    temp.x = event->x();
    temp.y = event->y();


    pts.push_back(temp);

    cout << "Added point (" << pts.back().x << ", " << pts.back().y << ") " << endl;
    cout << "Number of points: " << pts.size() << endl;
    num_pts++;

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pts.size(), &pts, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    update();
}

void GLWidget::initializeGL() {
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glPointSize(4.0f);

    // Create a new Vertex Array Object on the GPU which
    // saves the attribute layout of our vertices.
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    // Create a buffer on the GPU for position data
    glGenBuffers(1, &positionBuffer);

    // Upload the position data to the GPU, storing
    // it in the buffer we just allocated.
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    // Load our vertex and fragment shaders into a program object
    // on the GPU
    program = loadShaders(":/vert.glsl", ":/frag.glsl");

    // Bind the attribute "position" (defined in our vertex shader)
    // to the currently bound buffer object, which contains our
    // position data for a single triangle. This information 
    // is stored in our vertex array object.
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    GLint positionIndex = glGetAttribLocation(program, "position");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionIndex);
    glVertexAttribPointer(positionIndex, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glUseProgram(program);
    projectionMatrixLoc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "ProjectionMatrix");

    glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionMatrixLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(ortho));
}

void GLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h) {
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    ortho = glm::ortho(0.0f, (float)w, (float)h, 0.0f);

    glUseProgram(program);
// problem area?
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionMatrixLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(ortho));
}

void GLWidget::paintGL() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(program);

    // draw primitives based on the current draw mode
    glDrawArrays(drawMode, 0, num_pts);

    // draw points so we can always see them
    // glPointSize adjusts the size of point
    // primitives
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, num_pts);
}

// Copied from LoadShaders.cpp in the the oglpg-8th-edition.zip
// file provided by the OpenGL Programming Guide, 8th edition.
const GLchar* GLWidget::readShader(const char* filename) {
#ifdef WIN32
    FILE* infile;
    fopen_s(&infile, filename, "rb");
#else
    FILE* infile = fopen(filename, "rb");
#endif // WIN32

    if (!infile) {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        std::cerr << "Unable to open file '" << filename << "'" << std::endl;
#endif /* DEBUG */
        return NULL;
    }

    fseek(infile, 0, SEEK_END);
    int len = ftell(infile);
    fseek(infile, 0, SEEK_SET);

    GLchar* source = new GLchar[len + 1];

    fread(source, 1, len, infile);
    fclose(infile);

    source[len] = 0;

    return const_cast<const GLchar*>(source);
}

GLuint GLWidget::loadShaders(const char* vertf, const char* fragf) {
    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();

    // read vertex shader from Qt resource file
    QFile vertFile(vertf);
    vertFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text);
    QString vertString;
    QTextStream vertStream(&vertFile);
    vertString.append(vertStream.readAll());
    std::string vertSTLString = vertString.toStdString();

    const GLchar* vertSource = vertSTLString.c_str();

    GLuint vertShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertShader, 1, &vertSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertShader);
    {
        GLint compiled;
        glGetShaderiv(vertShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled);
        if (!compiled) {
            GLsizei len;
            glGetShaderiv(vertShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len);

            GLchar* log = new GLchar[len + 1];
            glGetShaderInfoLog(vertShader, len, &len, log);
            std::cout << "Shader compilation failed: " << log << std::endl;
            delete[] log;
        }
    }
    glAttachShader(program, vertShader);

    // read fragment shader from Qt resource file
    QFile fragFile(fragf);
    fragFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text);
    QString fragString;
    QTextStream fragStream(&fragFile);
    fragString.append(fragStream.readAll());
    std::string fragSTLString = fragString.toStdString();

    const GLchar* fragSource = fragSTLString.c_str();

    GLuint fragShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragShader, 1, &fragSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragShader);
    {
        GLint compiled;
        glGetShaderiv(fragShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled);
        if (!compiled) {
            GLsizei len;
            glGetShaderiv(fragShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len);

            GLchar* log = new GLchar[len + 1];
            glGetShaderInfoLog(fragShader, len, &len, log);
            std::cerr << "Shader compilation failed: " << log << std::endl;
            delete[] log;
        }
    }
    glAttachShader(program, fragShader);

    glLinkProgram(program);
    {
        GLint linked;
        glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linked);
        if (!linked) {
            GLsizei len;
            glGetProgramiv(program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len);

            GLchar* log = new GLchar[len + 1];
            glGetProgramInfoLog(program, len, &len, log);
            std::cout << "Shader linker failed: " << log << std::endl;
            delete[] log;
        }
    }

    return program;
}
```

The Header File:

```
#ifndef __GLWIDGET__INCLUDE__
#define __GLWIDGET__INCLUDE__

#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <vector>

// glm by default uses degrees, but that functionality
// is deprecated so GLM_FORCE_RADIANS turns off some 
// glm warnings
#define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS

using glm::vec2;

class GLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~GLWidget();

protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);
    void paintGL();

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);

private:
    GLuint loadShaders(const char* vertf, const char* fragf);
    static const GLchar* readShader(const char* filename);

    GLuint vao;
    GLuint program;

    GLuint positionBuffer;
    GLint projectionMatrixLoc;

    bool outline;
    GLenum drawMode;

    glm::mat4 ortho;

    int next;

    std::vector<vec2> pts;
    int num_pts;
};

#endif
```

My Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330

in vec2 position;

uniform mat4 ProjectionMatrix;

void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, 0, 1)*ProjectionMatrix;
}
```

My Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330

out vec4 color_out;

void main() {
  color_out = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
}
```

Comment: Usually, matrix operations in glsl are written in Matrix * Vector form. Have you tried `ProjectionMatrix * vec4(position.x, position.y, 0, 1)`?

Comment: Yeah I've tried both ways, I get the issue no matter what I change in the shader really. That's why I think it might have to do with loading the uniform variable, but again I'm totally unsure at this point